# why "I think therefore I am" not "I think therefore I am thinking"?

Tags: existence, descartes

why "thinking" jumped into the conclusion of "existence" as things can exist without thinking too. and what are all the other method except this that could prove our existence?

Comment: Thinking when with reflection on the process of thinking (what _cogito_ is) immediately (this is not a logical inference at all and needs not to be) opens that there is  somebody or something monitoring the process intimately. Here is then the existence. "To know is to know that I know". We don't have to prove our existence.

Comment: No, To know is to "think and come to know" that you know.  "I know" is a result that thinking produces it.

Comment: You are speaking now of the focusing on the final judgement when the object of the thought is "whether I know or not". I was speaking about a reflection accompanying a thought about, say a "this tree". When I think about the tree and reflect, while still thinking tree, at that thinking, I automatically bring about the existence of a subject besides the object. Reflection is the splitting of the thought process, not changing the object.

Comment: Things can exist without thinking, but can they think without existing? More to the point, how does "I" come out of "thinking"? Like other "methods", this one is flawed at "proving" something if one is determined enough to doubt it.

Comment: @Conifold which existence do that "they" need for thinking? and "I" is just what has been presupposed already "I think": we presuppose even before we are proving our existence?

Comment: I am not saying it is false.

Comment: Even if "thinking" is granted "I think" is a leap based on empirical association (to a "subject") that defeats the purpose of "proving". Once you have that, "I exist" is a trivial inference from definitions of the words. But then follow further existential leaps known as the [Cartesian Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_circle). You should read the linked answers.

Comment: Also see: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/55469/33787

Comment: Actually in eastern philosophy – Vedanta, Buddhism, Taoism, Zen... – its the other way round. Thinking is a disturbance and disorder imposed on being. The discussion in the other question linked by @christo183 has useful pointers.

Comment: Your reformulation to "I think therefore I am thinking" has the same dialectical force as the original. It still brings us to the "I am", and that was point.