# Is this is more stable version of Descartes experiment?

Tags: skepticism, rationalism, epsitemology

Everyone knows Descartes old experiment now.

He concludes with absolute certainty that “I am, I exist”. However this could very well be a delusion, since the evil genius could have corrupted the mind to think that, or there a theories creating doubt like “we are all one”.

I feel like a more bulletproof argument is: “something exists”. Any form of skepticism, doubt, delusion, incorrectness or falsity around that statement is itself “something”, and so it literally can’t be denied, since denying is something.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could 'cogito ergo sum' possibly be false?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70/could-cogito-ergo-sum-possibly-be-false) See the accepted answer.

Comment: "experiment"???? The [Cogito is not an argument, but an intuition](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/87084/can-cogito-ergo-sum-be-formalized).

Comment: See also [Are there any certainties besides "Cogito, ergo sum"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/56339/are-there-any-certainties-besides-cogito-ergo-sum) as well as [Did Peirce hold that, when stripped to its absolute core, Descartes’ cogito could be summarized as: ‘There is an Idea’?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/100546/did-peirce-hold-that-when-stripped-to-its-absolute-core-descartes-cogito-coul)

Comment: The stable version is 'My horse thinks I am, therefore I am'.

Comment: It could be said that you're not wrong yet it's very vague about that 'something' with maximum randomness, maybe 'some process exists' would be better metaphysically? Yet the existence of some process implies something else such as 'imbalance' interpreted as not *justly* to be balanced...

Answer (score 2):

You may well be right. Compare:-

> Some critics have complained that, in referring to the “I”, Descartes begs the question by presupposing what he means to establish in the “I exist.” Among the critics, Bertrand Russell objects that “the word ‘I’ is really illegitimate.” Echoing the 18th century thinker, Georg Lichtenberg, Russell writes that Descartes should have, instead, stated “his ultimate premiss in the form ‘there are thoughts’.” Russell adds that “the word ‘I’ is grammatically convenient, but does not describe a datum” (1945, 567). Accordingly, “there is pain” and “I am in pain” have different contents, and Descartes is entitled only to the former."
> [Stanford Encyclopaedia of Philosophy - Descartes' Epistemology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-epistemology/) especially section 4.1